# My VS Code cannot connect to internet, I can't download a extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

So I just installed VS code on my new windows. then I try can't download the extension. I've tried changing the DNS and turning off the firewall but it's still the same. I tried downloading the extension manual and it worked.

This pict is my vscode went I open it

([image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69l80.png)]

[image: Error]

I've also tried downloading the insider version and it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it with system installer. My Vscode now can install